# Elasticsearch parent child shout return parent instead of child

Tags: elasticsearch

I guess I need some help with `ElasticSearch`.

I have a `parent child` mapping and I would like to search for documents containing the word in either the parent **or** in the child document. Think of a SO question and the answers. There is `1:n` questions to answers. I would like to get the questions where the `SeachWord` is in the question (parent) and I would also like to get the question if the `SearchWord` is in any child answer even if the SearchWord is not in the question.

This is my query and the result is the child document but I was expecting to get the parent document.

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "should": [{
                "query_string": {
                    "query": "SearchWord"
                }
            },
            {
                "has_child": {
                    "type": "answers",
                    "query": {
                        "match": {
                            "_all": "SearchWord"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }]
        }
    },
    "size": 1
}
```

Thanks for your help!

**UPDATE**

The query is totally correct my only mistake was to run the query against the index.

**Worng:** cUrl /index/_search

**Correct:** cUrl /index/parenttype/_search

I hope this helps anyone who has problems with parent child searches ;-)

Regards
Phillip

Answer (score -1, accepted):

your answer is not exactly what I was looking for but i gave my the right direction.
I have to **query the parent type** instead of the whole index. So this is my solution which is working like expected.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "has_child": {
            "type": "answers",
            "query": {
              "query_string": {
                "query": "SearchWord"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        { 
            "query_string" : {
                "query": "SearchWord" 
            } 
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "size": 1
}
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: I am just curious what is wrong with my query :) what was not working?

Comment: Your answer was to query the child type and look for the parent documents. I just wanted it to be the other way around. When I was testing it first, I was still using the index and not the type so I received the child document. That's the reason why I was thinking your answer didn't quite fit. But as I said **your answer leaded the way** ;-) Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You should query child and [filter on parent](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/has-parent.html)

**cUrl /indexName/childType**

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "has_parent": {
            "type": "questions",
            "query": {
              "query_string": {
                "query": "SearchWord"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "_all": "SearchWord"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "size": 1
}
```